# How to get mouse position in draw event (before modal or invoke)?

Tags: python

Let say, I want to make a Gizmo, that will react with mouse position. So these events are perfect for me:

```
class MyGizmo(bpy.types.Gizmo):
    def draw(self, context):
        print("draw")

    def draw_select(self, context, select_id=0):
        print("draw select")
```

But to get mouse position, typically the `Modal` event is used, which have a `event` property with mouse position. But I want to get mouse position before the `Invoke`. So maybe I can get mouse position differently?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you're looking for? Because, before Invoking, there's nothing to run. If you want something to capture mouse positions constantly, you need another Operator that is already running modal before your gizmo invokation. Blender uses a simple [input > call active operators > draw] loop, and any operator that isn't active will be skipped.

Comment: @Secrop, I want to build an gizmo like a Loop Cut, which runs after select tool. Whose evens runs then I need, only problem that where is no event data here

Comment: then you need another operator just for capturing the mouse position, and telling blender to PassThrough so other operators can be invoked/execute. For example, LoopCut is not a single operator, but a collection of them, with one that is running modal and calls the others based on User's input.

Comment: @Secrop, can you explain how to run this operator from gizmo group events like setup or poll?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not deeply familiarized with gizmos/gizmogroups to give you a straight answer.. but afaik, they are mainly wrappers for modal operators with automatic draw calls.